# Absolutely convergent infinite product

Tags: number-theory

I have read about the definition of the product
$$\prod_{j\in J}a_j\in[1,+\infty]$$
when $a_j\in[1,+\infty)$ for all $j\in J$, where $J$ is any set, possibly infinite. It is defined as the supremem of the set:
$$S = \left\{\prod_{i\in I}\mid I\subset J\text{ is finite}\right\}.$$
However, this does not cover the famous
$$\zeta(s)=\prod_p (1-p^{-s})^{-1}$$
because $(1-p^{-s})^{-1}$ are not real numbers. How is the definition of infinite product extended to cover this famous case? Also, what is absolute convergence?

Comment: See Rudin's RCA for  a thorough discussion of infinite products of complex numbers.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Thank you for your recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to define it (not the most general possible definition, but enough to cover the case that you ask about). If $a_n\neq 0$ for all $n\geq 1$ then the infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is defined to be the limit of $\prod_{n=1}^Na_n$ as $N\to\infty$ if this exists and is not zero.

It follows from this definition that (provided none of the $a_n$ are zero) $\prod a_n$ exists if and only if $\prod a_n^{-1}$ exists, and that

$$ \prod a_n^{-1} = \left(\prod a_n\right)^{-1}.$$

It follows from the limit existing that $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=1$, so we often change variables and instead talk about $\prod (1+a_n)$. This converges absolutely by definition if $\prod(1+\lvert a_n\rvert)$ converges, which happens if and only if $\sum \lvert a_n\rvert$ converges.

Therefore, for example, you can define
$$ \prod_{p} \left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1} = \left( \lim_{N\to\infty} \prod_{p\leq N}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)\right)^{-1},$$

which exists (and is neither zero nor infinity) for $\Re (s)>1$ because the product converges absolutely, because $\sum_p \frac{1}{p^\sigma}$ converges when $\sigma>1$.

This definition is trying to capture the intuition that `$\prod (1+a_n)=\exp(\sum\log (1+a_n))'$, which one needs to be slightly careful of because you're taking complex logarithms (this is easily avoided by taking a suitable choice of logarithm, but I prefer the approach above). The relevance of $\sum \lvert a_n\rvert$ converging is that it is a sufficient (but not necessary) condition for $\sum \log(1+\lvert a_n\rvert)$ to converge.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the defn, we have the $a_n$ nicely ordered by $n=1,2,3\ldots$, however later we have the primes $p$ not ordered this way, instead $p\le N$ is considered. This is confusing. I get the gist of it, but still I am uncomfortable. Shouldn't the defn be extended notationally to include an expression like $p\le N$? Also, I do not get what the last paragraph is saying, would you please explain more?